# Trying to set only long options in my Bash script but getting "Error parsing" message

Tags: bash, getopt

I'm currently trying to set up my machine learning experiment to use Bash long options for Python arguments but am getting a parsing error. My script looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1,2,3"

script_name=$(basename "$0")
long=learning_rate:,batch_size

TEMP=$(getopt --long $long --name "$script_name" -- "$@")

eval set -- "${TEMP}"

while :; do
    case "${1}" in
        --learning_rate       ) LEARNING_RATE=$2;             shift 2 ;;
        --batch_size     ) BATCH_SIZE=$2;           shift 2 ;;
        *                 ) echo "Error parsing"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

python some_script.py \
    --learning_rate $LEARNING_RATE \
    --batch_size "$BATCH_SIZE"
```

I'm not that familiar with Bash and am wondering where the code went wrong. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: According to `man 1 getopt` the proper long option name for long options is `--longoptions` not `--long`??

Comment: What exactly goes wrong, and under what circumstances? Do you get an error message? Also, which version of `getopt` do you have? The Linux version works significantly differently from the "standard" unix version (which is badly broken in some ways). See [Complex Option Parsing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing) in Greycat's Wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Adding short options seems to fix the issue:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0,1,2,3"

script_name=$(basename "$0")
long=learning_rate:,batch_size:

TEMP=$(getopt --longoptions $long --name "$script_name" -o r:s: -- "$@")

eval set -- "${TEMP}"

while test "$1" != "--"; do
    case "${1}" in
        --learning_rate) LEARNING_RATE=$2; shift 2 ;;
        --batch_size   ) BATCH_SIZE=$2;    shift 2 ;;
        *) echo "Error parsing"; exit 1;;
    esac
done

python some_script.py \
    --learning_rate $LEARNING_RATE \
    --batch_size "$BATCH_SIZE"
```